# InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] - laravel, faker, phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit, faker

Since I am developing package, so I put my factories to custom path like this:

```
-- app

-- packages

-----mockizart

-------blog

---------database

--------------factories

----------------- PageModelFactory.php

---------src
```

this is how i load factory in my service provider (I already make sure the path is correct by clicking it on phpstorm):

```php
function boot()
{
 Factory::construct($this->app->make(\Faker\Generator::class), __DIR__."/../database/factories");
}
```

this is my page model factory (I already made sure this file was really loaded):

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
use Mockizart\Blog\Dodols\PageModel;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;


$factory->define(PageModel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => "retretre",
        'slug' => "retretret",
        'type' => 0,
        'category' => 0,
        'tags' => "",
        'content' => "",
    ];
});
```

and this is my script test :

```php
use Mockizart\Blog\Dodols\PageModel;
    .....
    .....
/** @test */
public function edit_page()
{
   dd(PageModel::find(1)); <-- this return was NULL so I think my class and namespace does exist.

   factory(PageModel::class)->make(); <-- this cause error "unable to locate factory......"
   $response = $this->get('/blog/page/edit/15');
   $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you are using `orchestra\Testbench`, the correct way to load custom factories is in the `setUp()` method of your Test class or TestCase **NOT** in your `Service Provider`.

the code would be like this:

```
class TestCase extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase
{
   public function setUp(): void
   {
     parent::setUp();
     // additional setup
     $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations');
     $this->withFactories(__DIR__.'/../database/factories');
   }

   protected function getPackageProviders($app)
   {
       return BlogServiceProvider::class;
   }
}
```